# statsmodels.api error while importing pandas Int64Index

Tags: python

When I try to import the following library:

> > import statsmodels.api as sm
> > I recibe the following error: "cannot import name 'Int64Index' from 'pandas'"

I guess Pandas should have upgraded to a new version where they deleted this 'Int64Index', but I'm not sure, can anyone help?

Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

Same error message for me, manually installing the latest statsmodels library fixed it for me:

```
pip uninstall statsmodels
pip install statsmodels==0.14.0
```